# index.html to jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I write this in jquery? I want to display a image 600x400 inside the div block on click?

```
<script>
function displayImage() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerhtml ="image.jpg";

}
</script>

<form>

<input type="submit" onClick="displayImage()">
</form>

<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this is just a typo in putting the question together, but 'script' is misspelled in the opening `<script>` tag.

Comment: Why using a form for... that ? :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#demo").html("image.jpg");
```

However, "image.jpg" is not HTML. So you should just use:

```
$("#demo").text("image.jpg");
```

If you are trying to add an image to the div, use:

```
$("#demo").html('<img src="image.jpg" />');
```

Comment: nice. how would i do it  say if i click a link and I have 2 to 10 links and I want all the itemsor images from link to show up in the demo div block? -thanks

Comment: @mcgrailm, you need to get out more ;)

Comment: @user244394, you could do `$(".SomeClass").append('<img src="image.jpg" />');` Or something like that. You selector and data you are appending would need to change.

Comment: @Abe that maybe so but to display 600x400 text on a web page  ? can't tell me that's not funny

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want *only* the image to be displayed within the `#demo` (and also assuming you want this to happen on form submission):

```
$('form').submit(
    function() {
        $('#demo').html('<img src="path/to/image.jpg" />');
        return false;
    }
);
```

If, instead, you want to *add* an image to the `#demo` (though still assuming this is on form submit):

```
$('form').submit(
    function() {
        $('<img src="path/to/image.jpg" />').appendTo('#demo');
        return false;
    }
);
```

---

Just a quick note, but it seemed worth mentioning:

1. the above all need to be enclosed by a `$(document).ready(/*...*/)` (or equivalent).
2. the `onClick` inline click-handler is no longer required if the above is used, and might actively complicate matters if it remains in place.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want the image to be displayed... change your html to look like so:

```
<input type="submit" id="SubmitButtonId" />
<img id="demo" src="someimage.jpg" />
```

and your javascript to:

```
<script>

    $(function(){
        $('#SubmitButtonId').live('click', function(){
            $('#demo').src('image.jpg');
        });
    });
</script>
```